# How to add pagination to PHAsset fetching from Photos Framework?

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, phasset, photosframework

I am trying to get all the photos from cameraRoll using Photos framework but its taking a lot of time to fetch all the photos from cameraRoll.

Is their anyway to add pagination to it ? 
so i can fetch while scrolling.

```
 var images = [UIImage]()
 var assets = [PHAsset]()

fileprivate func assetsFetchOptions() -> PHFetchOptions {
    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()

    //fetchOptions.fetchLimit = 40 //uncomment to limit photo

    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    return fetchOptions
}

fileprivate func fetchPhotos() {
    let allPhotos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: assetsFetchOptions())

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        allPhotos.enumerateObjects({ (asset, count, stop) in
            //print(count)

            let imageManager = PHImageManager.default()
            let targetSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
            let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
            options.isSynchronous = true
            imageManager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: targetSize, contentMode: .aspectFit, options: options, resultHandler: { (image, info) in

                if let image = image {
                    self.images.append(image)
                    self.assets.append(asset)
                }

                if count == allPhotos.count - 1 {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                    }
                }

            })

        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't fetch all photos in one go.It will definitely take more time as your number of images in gallery increases.So start fetching images only when you are required just like SDWebImages.Write you fetching code in cellForItemAtIndexPath of UICollectionView datasource method.Each cell fetches only one image.

Comment: By using objects(at:)  i am fetching images while scrolling. thanks

Comment: Help others by sharing the code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`allPhotos` is of type [PHFetchResult](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phfetchresult)< PHAsset > which is a lazy collection, ie it doesn't actually go out and get the photo until you ask it for one, which is what `.enumerateObjects` is doing.  You can just grab the photos one at a time with the [subscript operator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phfetchresult/1621000-subscript) or get a range of objects with [objects(at:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phfetchresult/1621008-objects) to page through the collection as needed.

Comment: can you please explain how we would use objects(at:) to page